# What could have afflicted Paul in 2 Corinthians 1 so much as to have him despairing of life itself in Asia?

Tags: acts, 2-corinthians

2 Corinthians 1:8 (NKJV)

> 8 For we do not want you to be ignorant, brethren, of our  trouble which came to us in Asia: that we were burdened  beyond measure, above strength, so that we despaired even  of life.

Acts 19:23 (NKJV)

> 23 And about that time there arose a great commotion  about the Way. 24 For a certain man named Demetrius, a  silversmith, who made silver shrines of Diana, d brought no  small profit to the craftsmen. 25 He called them together  with the workers of similar occupation, and said: “Men, you  know that we have our prosperity by this trade. 26  Moreover you see and hear that not only at Ephesus, but  throughout almost all Asia, this Paul has persuaded and  turned away many people, saying that they are not gods  which are made with hands. 27 So not only is this trade of  ours in danger of falling into disrepute, but also the temple  of the great goddess Diana may be despised and her  magnificence destroyed, e whom all Asia and the world  worship.”  28 Now when they heard  this, they were full of wrath and  cried out, saying, “Great is Diana of the Ephesians!”  29 So  the whole city was filled with confusion, and rushed into the  theater with one accord, having seized Gaius and  Aristarchus, Macedonians, Paul’s travel companions. 30  And when Paul wanted to go in to the people, the disciples  would not allow him.

Paul speaks of trouble in Asia that burdened him so much,could it be the incident in Ephesus in acts 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2 Corinthians 1:8-11, Paul is telling the Corinthians of his illness while in the Roman province of Asia, during which he felt ready to die, and how he attributed his recovery to God, because of those who prayed for him (1:8-11):

> [2 Corinthians 1:8-11](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/2-Corinthians-Chapter-1/): For we would not, brethren, have you ignorant of our trouble which came to us in Asia, that we were pressed out of measure, above strength, insomuch that we despaired even of life: But we had the sentence of death in ourselves, that we should not trust in ourselves, but in God which raiseth the dead: Who delivered us from so great a death, and doth deliver: in whom we trust that he will yet deliver us; Ye also helping together by prayer for us, that for the gift bestowed upon us by the means of many persons thanks may be given by many on our behalf.

The word translated here in verse 1:9 as 'sentence' is a biblical hapax legomenon, and is considered more correctly translated as 'answer'. The Very Rev. E. H. Plumptre (*[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/2_corinthians/1.htm)*) says this "was probably a half-technical term, used in medical practice" as referring to a diagnosis. So, the [New Living Translation](http://biblehub.com/nlt/2_corinthians/1.htm) provides a less literal but possibly more correct translation, "`In fact, we expected to die.`"

Overall, verse 9 does not appear to refer to imprisonment under sentence of death and then release from prison. Paul had expected to die because he had become so ill that death seemed inevitable, but he trusted in God who can raise even the dead and believed he was helped by the prayers of many. This, he says, is the reason he had not returned to Corinth.

In Paul's time, many ailments could have resulted in death, but he does not give us any clue as to what afflicted him, other than that he suffered distress and loss of energy. An alternative hypothesis could be that he exaggerated a minor ailment because he realised the need to explain his long absence from Corinth.

According to [Acts 18:1](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Acts-Chapter-18/), Paul had just left Corinth, on his way through Asia to Jerusalem when the riot occurred in Acts 19:23ff. Therefore, he could not have given this as a reason for not having visited Corinth.